# Print a number of items in list depending on request from spinbox (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a list of items and want them to print in order, depending on the number requested from a spinbox, how would i go about this?

example:

```
list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'cow', 'snake']
```

if spinbox = 2
show cat, dog

(i'm new to python so i have the code for the list and spinbox but have no idea how to write a function that will work for this)

Comment: you can learn how to manipulate python list, even you are new to python, try it first by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in list[:spinbox_value]:
    print element
```

This will print all elements from list in range from 0 (inclusive) to spinbox_value (exclusive), to standard output. If the list will be large (thousands of items) and that printing will be often (several times per second), then do this version:

```
for index in xrange(0, spinbox_value):
    print list[index]
```

The first version uses copy (list[:spinbox_value] copies part of the list), that's why its going to be slightly slower.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys

list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'cow', 'snake']
spinbox = input("Enter Spinbox")
x=0
for i in list:
   if(x>spinbox-1):
       break
   print i
   x=x+1
```

Hope This Helps!!